# LG P760, insufficient disk space, help please

Tags: sd-card, insufficient-memory, partitions, lg

I have an LG P760 updated to the latest available by LG version. 
The last couple of days I cannot update the installed apps with the known error of insufficient disk space, although it was supposed that more than 290MB where available. I removed some apps and increased the free space to 320MB. Then I managed to update some apps but that's it.

Now, I understand that this is complicated but I want to know the following:
a. Is is possible to partition my external SD and use it as internal storage?
b. I want to avoid to root the device. If it's not possible, is it possible to root the device and then un-root it? 
c. I want to avoid apps like link2sd. I am fairly competent with Linux CLI, so, I would like to use the mount command and Android boot scripts in order to mount SD partition.

Can I do that?

---

### New Info:

It is possible that I found a "bug"(?). I had 2 devices and both of them were under my account in the Play store. I gave the second one to my wife. For a reason that I don't understand, my device was "removed" from my devices list, but the device that I gave to my wife was not (and it was in my wife's account too!). 
I wanted to install an application and since I could not do that from my phone, I decided to try to "push" the application. But Play store said that my device was not compatible (and it showed the device of my wife). Then, I hide it, hoping that my device will re-appear. 
Instead of that, my upgraded the apps that until some minutes ago refused to do so with the "insufficient" storage message!

Comment: Looks like you already researched a lot of background, but just in case: have you seen our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)? It might have the one or other item left for you (on the first paragraph – no experience with the second, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

a) Yes, you can use your external as an internal storage. (Requires Root access. Using link2sd. I don't know any other app)

b) Yes, it is possible to unroot your device. (http://www.wikihow.com/Unroot-Android)

C) I haven't tried that. But, yes you can do it.

I think that you want to avoid using link2sd app because of the risk.So I suggest you move your apps from Internal memory to an External memory(if you have any).
By rooting your phone your warranty will be void, plus you take a huge risk.(But if anything goes wrong, you are not alone. So you'll always find a solution on net :p )
This is the biggest disadvantage. But on the bright side there are plenty of things you can enjoy.

Comment: I want to avoid link2sd because: a. It's not free, b. It's just a link. A more elegant solution would be something like LVM but I suppose that LVM is not part of the kernel :) Anyway, yes, the idea is to remove useless applications (like for example Google Movies) and mount the external SD partition as a storage device. OK, so, I need to learn where applications and their data are stored (the path, I mean). Can someone point me a relevant (small) document?